# dotnet restore fails with error MSB4062: The "CheckForImplicitPackageReferenceOverrides" task could not be loaded

Tags: .net-core

I recently installed the alpha preview .NET Core version and set MSBuildSdksPath to point to it. After that dotnet publish and even dotnet restore failed so I removed the environment variable, but now it fails with this:

```
error MSB4062: The "CheckForImplicitPackageReferenceOverrides" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.103\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\..\tools\netcoreapp2.0/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.dll. Assembly with same name is already loaded Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [c:\Workspace\Telesis\Configuration.Repositories\Configuration.Repositories.csproj]
```

Comment: Since your question is three months old I wonder if you have found an answer by now? I face the same error message when executing "DotNetCorePack" command in a Cake script and cannot resolve it.

Comment: Yes, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9759 I found this:

> If you encounter the error and haven't set MSBuildSdksPath, then you can try `dotnet build-server shutdown`

I ran `dotnet build-server shutdown` and after that `dotnet restore` worked.